# shell script blocking process

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu

I wrote a one small shell script(demo_script) and the content are following

**exec > /tmp/log 2>&1
   sudo apt-get install -y telnet**

i used "bash demo_script &" to run this script as daemon. But it doesn't install software and keep on running in background.

After captured process details used "ps -ef"

root     28882 28881  0 13:35 pts/0    00:00:00 sudo apt-get install -y telnet

root     28883 28882  1 13:35 pts/0    00:00:00 apt-get install -y telnet

root     28901 28883  0 13:35 pts/0    00:00:00 apt-get install -y telnet

i don't know why its created like this.

and log message also

**Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  telnet
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 71 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/67.1 kB of archives.
After this operation, 167 kB of additional disk space will be used.**

Comment: Does the machine have internet access?

Comment: Run it without the framework and see what happens:  `sudo apt-get install -y telnet &`

Answer (score 0):

It's waiting for user input.  use "--yes" or something:  http://linux.die.net/man/8/apt-get

Comment: of course, i executed command as "non-interactively mode" ( apt-get install -y telnet)